# How to get strings inside of json array if there are no tags separating it?

Tags: android, arrays, json

This is formatted json:

```
{
   "build":42606,
   "torrents":[
      [
         "084D1BDC1FDF82264A3554E59B64BAA3579D5F0E",
         136,
         "Terminator.Genisys.2015.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         2822006528,
         1000,
         2822006528,
         26460160,
         9,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "a20a7306",
         1459594469,
         1459605260,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Terminator.Genisys.2015.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         0,
         "4F292253"
      ],
      [
         "12B3CD13C55736D3628FFAF03729F20AF9C4F8B8",
         136,
         "Deadwood.S01.S02.S03.Complete.720p.X264.anoXmous",
         15842766215,
         1000,
         15851187591,
         495731725,
         31,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "73df595a",
         1465650191,
         1476891125,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Deadwood.S01.S02.S03.Complete.720p.X264.anoXmous",
         0,
         "835CC3D4"
      ],
      [
         "1ED3FC20FB7B124B8517FDB45A419819322EB430",
         136,
         "Captain.America.Civil.War.2016.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         3431757620,
         1000,
         3431790388,
         1146880,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "54da6a47",
         1474567765,
         1475745737,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Captain.America.Civil.War.2016.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         0,
         "0258A882"
      ],
      [
         "205A8A81E5B72F109005710B8EBE868FF99D47AD",
         136,
         "Black.Mirror.2011.S01.SLOSubs.DVDRip.XviD-SCC",
         1308362787,
         1000,
         1308362787,
         11862016,
         9,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "32e25ce4",
         1475870101,
         1476030010,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Black.Mirror.2011.S01.SLOSubs.DVDRip.XviD-SCC",
         0,
         "B471014B"
      ],
      [
         "266B8FF68B56DAB45948422472F6889BC4600BCB",
         136,
         "Hardcore.Henry.2015.SLOSubs.DVDRip.XviD-DrSi",
         1504050669,
         1000,
         1504050669,
         3358720,
         2,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "54da6a43",
         1474567616,
         1474573185,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Hardcore.Henry.2015.SLOSubs.DVDRip.XviD-DrSi",
         0,
         "E0923AE7"
      ],
      [
         "27C1E716F202ADE4602531340BEC6E3B56FF48F6",
         136,
         "The.Lobster.2015.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         2474087019,
         1000,
         2474087019,
         1720320,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "a20a730b",
         1459594461,
         1459604065,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\The.Lobster.2015.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         0,
         "C12365B2"
      ],
      [
         "2C8988AC16E890C479E66A10DAEA7EFE80CA9BD5",
         136,
         "The.Nice.Guys.2016.SLOSubs.720p.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         3979341483,
         1000,
         3979538091,
         5668864,
         1,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "54da6a49",
         1474568017,
         1476007444,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\The.Nice.Guys.2016.SLOSubs.720p.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         0,
         "6FA36915"
      ],
      [
         "2D583F86019AF1C3255318434795E401D28C2A42",
         136,
         "The 100 - Season 1 Complete - ChameE",
         1764398491,
         1000,
         1797952923,
         752216886,
         418,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "92b6df0d",
         1465643724,
         1465658168,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\The 100 - Season 1 Complete - ChameE",
         0,
         "57F40AB4"
      ],
      [
         "2DBE408C575246FA5BDE7A7C08B58D4CF334BF2A",
         136,
         "The.Elder.Scrolls.V.Skyrim.Legendary.Edition-WaLMaRT",
         14012789923,
         723,
         10138907811,
         13615104,
         1,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         47270,
         1,
         3873914880,
         "",
         "",
         "Stopped 72.3 %",
         "fc996e5d",
         1475151155,
         0,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\The.Elder.Scrolls.V.Skyrim.Legendary.Edition-WaLMaRT",
         0,
         "1908DDF3"
      ],
      [
         "4378666D8A6BCFBE1640629C0EFC05691930919B",
         136,
         "Legend.2015.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         2912295322,
         1000,
         0,
         2277376,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "a20a7308",
         1459594469,
         1459594741,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Legend.2015.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         0,
         "1B32519E"
      ],
      [
         "440B0AC8BAADF9394900B431A59C3A237FDCFE5B",
         136,
         "TWENTY ONE PILOTS - DISCOGRAPHY (2009-15)",
         741321898,
         1000,
         742370474,
         9355264,
         12,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "234c1a19",
         1475605160,
         1476021216,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\TWENTY ONE PILOTS - DISCOGRAPHY (2009-15)",
         0,
         "A50394AA"
      ],
      [
         "44E4BE427506FBFB5BF1958B0D536B23431EEC42",
         136,
         "The Do Over 2016 720p WEBRip x264.mp4",
         1602822762,
         1000,
         1602822762,
         888586240,
         554,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "d934c8d9",
         1465229127,
         1465473660,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads",
         0,
         "C114EE01"
      ],
      [
         "4D8A586D25273083630D448A7B2802A3F6B4B3FF",
         136,
         "The.Witcher.3_Wild.Hunt-Game.of.the.Year.Edition-Black.Box",
         27715377657,
         55,
         1528987648,
         144916480,
         94,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         3451,
         2,
         26186390009,
         "",
         "",
         "Stopped 5.5 %",
         "7f716c8",
         1476012913,
         0,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\The.Witcher.3_Wild.Hunt-Game.of.the.Year.Edition-Black.Box",
         0,
         "FDABDBB3"
      ],
      [
         "5563D6A4C5C8F67AFBB92832396942CBAE18AAA5",
         136,
         "Everybody.Wants.Some!!.2016.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         2582164468,
         1000,
         2582164468,
         34193408,
         13,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "54da6a42",
         1474567564,
         1475160531,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Everybody.Wants.Some!!.2016.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         0,
         "F4A9360F"
      ],
      [
         "63626016DB43514A96AC09FCB3262B9E6699E551",
         136,
         "Narcos.Complete.Season.2.2016.CROSubs.720p.WEBRip.XviD-HDVid",
         14710347522,
         1000,
         14735595266,
         604585984,
         41,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "54da6a41",
         1474566493,
         1476032719,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Narcos.Complete.Season.2.2016.CROSubs.720p.WEBRip.XviD-HDVid",
         0,
         "9B268512"
      ],
      [
         "6396C5D5FC9A8FA232FA278482847248AD19975C",
         136,
         "Warcraft.2016.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         2701287242,
         1000,
         2701287242,
         72605514,
         26,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "54da6a3f",
         1474566440,
         1475159248,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Warcraft.2016.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         0,
         "EBCBFD16"
      ],
      [
         "8C962835C0762AC651C40009325F1CA82C497A4E",
         136,
         "The.Dark.Knight.2008.SLOSubs.DVDRip.XviD-DrSi",
         1473314116,
         1000,
         1473330500,
         69992448,
         47,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "8af5d85f",
         1474639073,
         1475773687,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\The.Dark.Knight.2008.SLOSubs.DVDRip.XviD-DrSi",
         0,
         "65C4DB54"
      ],
      [
         "993CD9F34B194A4B05F87C451857F9A84205F391",
         136,
         "12 Monkeys S01 Season 01 Complete 480p HDTV x264 AAC E-Subs [GWC]",
         1992113106,
         1000,
         1992113106,
         1831287762,
         919,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "1d",
         1465990457,
         1465999660,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\12 Monkeys S01 Season 01 Complete 480p HDTV x264 AAC E-Subs [GWC]",
         0,
         "4D711958"
      ],
      [
         "A40CF513587DCB4E357F32D4EEF5FA22FC00B419",
         136,
         "Age.of.Empires.II.HD.The.African.Kingdoms-CODEX",
         2261948011,
         1000,
         2261948011,
         19972096,
         8,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "f0ea6d39",
         1471178190,
         1471251153,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Age.of.Empires.II.HD.The.African.Kingdoms-CODEX",
         0,
         "22B115FA"
      ],
      [
         "B1949C19DEA6BE31B324EC9BDD2A02DE6DA68DAF",
         136,
         "Age of Empires II + The Conquerors Expansion",
         535058945,
         1000,
         535058945,
         114688,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "f0ea6d38",
         1471178191,
         1471181744,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Age of Empires II + The Conquerors Expansion",
         0,
         "2A7DD632"
      ],
      [
         "B5B3F96DF541F3C7600715C12C2D0A216885383C",
         136,
         "Solace.2015.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         2264273769,
         1000,
         2264273769,
         11960320,
         5,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "a20a7309",
         1459594468,
         1459603265,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Solace.2015.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         0,
         "E7504915"
      ],
      [
         "BADE5A7A9D591BCDB5DC59B39A64232E3B631B60",
         136,
         "Zoolander.2.2016.HDRip.XViD-ETRG",
         741144534,
         1000,
         741144534,
         72269824,
         97,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "af8512e1",
         1463823614,
         1463826028,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Zoolander.2.2016.HDRip.XViD-ETRG",
         0,
         "3DCD447A"
      ],
      [
         "C9FAFA76E6FCE31E66828CB1419ABDAF803B5035",
         136,
         "Stronghold Crusader.rar",
         443822383,
         1000,
         443822383,
         5570560,
         12,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "f0ea6d3d",
         1471179809,
         1471181567,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads",
         0,
         "CB31D401"
      ],
      [
         "CE8357DED670F06329F6028D2F2CEA6F514646E0",
         136,
         "Zootopia 2016 1080p HDRip x264 AC3-JYK",
         2926361304,
         1000,
         2934749912,
         235499728,
         80,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "af8512de",
         1463823431,
         1465234867,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Zootopia 2016 1080p HDRip x264 AC3-JYK",
         0,
         "4469DAF6"
      ],
      [
         "D07B0DAB16BF8157B814DF27074CE715E11F27EA",
         136,
         "Westworld.S01E01.SLOSubs.720p.HDTV.x264-FLEET",
         1332100569,
         1000,
         1332100569,
         671744,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "256b6ca0",
         1475662529,
         1476027460,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Westworld.S01E01.SLOSubs.720p.HDTV.x264-FLEET",
         0,
         "F825F212"
      ],
      [
         "DE45A69835A597868DEF2E2FEF087D7B8DF61DD9",
         136,
         "Momentum.2015.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         2150385510,
         1000,
         2150385510,
         7815168,
         3,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "a20a7307",
         1459594469,
         1459603607,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Momentum.2015.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         0,
         "E011F7F1"
      ],
      [
         "EBE369A5762FE1E233E56BE90CA5D707F29B3D86",
         136,
         "Atlanta.S01E07.XviD-AFG",
         331629452,
         1000,
         331629452,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "575a24fa",
         1476528591,
         1476529013,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Atlanta.S01E07.XviD-AFG",
         0,
         "D828E9B8"
      ],
      [
         "EFF0C3EFD9C86646B337FE61CD637CCE59D4FD8E",
         201,
         "Anthropoid.2016.LiMiTED.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         2686178277,
         1000,
         2686178277,
         1074320357,
         399,
         51085,
         176,
         -1,
         "",
         4,
         57,
         0,
         5,
         129997,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Seeding 100.0 %",
         "2ab44b9d",
         1478857910,
         1478860313,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Anthropoid.2016.LiMiTED.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         0,
         "4DE9F939"
      ],
      [
         "F57D4098BC49996D12F0D89858A1284E1FE1DDC7",
         136,
         "London.Has.Fallen.2016.1080p.BluRay.6CH.ShAaNiG.mkv",
         1867896803,
         1000,
         1867913187,
         436268998,
         233,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "d934c8da",
         1465229126,
         1465473428,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads",
         0,
         "ECD71F0C"
      ],
      [
         "FDE79363FE8D0942ED745632100B313076C744C2",
         136,
         "The.Boss.2016.THEATRiCAL.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         2164785053,
         1000,
         2164785053,
         573440,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         "",
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         65536,
         -1,
         0,
         "",
         "",
         "Finished 100.0 %",
         "54da6a48",
         1474568002,
         1475745965,
         "",
         "C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\The.Boss.2016.THEATRiCAL.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi",
         0,
         "61DE02AC"
      ]
   ],
   "label":[

   ],
   "torrentc":"749574273",
   "rssfeeds":[

   ],
   "rssfilters":[

   ]
}
```

This is a taste of the json. As you can see there are just a bunch of values inside of the torrents json array. However, I do know what each of the values mean and they are always at the same spot.

I can't use

```
 jsonArray.getString("something") because there are no tags.
```

What would I put instead of this? Let's say I wanted to get

"084D1BDC1FDF82264A3554E59B64BAA3579D5F0E" this value out of the first index of the array, how would I get it? I know my question is all over the place,feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: your json is invalid. post whole json code

Comment: I added the entire JSON inside a pastebin. I've validated it online already.

Comment: Please don't use PasteBin, [edit] your question to include a valid sample of the JSON

Comment: Regarding, not knowing what those mean - are you using [Transmission](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/browser/trunk/extras/rpc-spec.txt)?

Comment: @cricket_007 no, i am using uTorrent.

Comment: Well, I'm sure documentation (and probably even a Java api) exists for that. That app bundles a bunch of malware in it, so it's not the best anyways

Comment: Yup [documentation here](http://help.utorrent.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1573947-torrent-labels-list---webapi) about what the values are

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you I've copied this to help with the parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can see there are just a bunch of values inside of the torrents json array.

No, there are a bunch of arrays inside the `torrents` array. Each of *those* arrays contains a series of values.

> What would I put instead of this?

Assuming that `jsonArray` is [a `JSONArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html), you would call `getString(0)`, `getInt(1)`, etc. on the inner arrays.

Comment: Yup. This was it. I did not know there's a JSON array inside the JSON array. 
                     JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);
                     jsonArray2.getString(0)

Answer (score 0):

Json format shoule be in Key-Value pairs.This json response seems invalid 
You can still try this to parse it

```
JSONOArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("torrents");
for(int i = 0;i < jsonArray.length();i++){
    JSONArray newArray = jsonArray.get(i);
    for(int j = 0;j < newArray.length();j++){
        //get All the values from the individual array
        String x = newArray.get(j);
    }
}eate its object
```

Now to store the array values 

 Create a pojo with relevant field names and in Inner for loop create its object and set the values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: The json looks terrible!

Try to use this structure:

```
{
    build : 123,
    torrents : [
        {
            id : 084D1BDC1FDF82264A3554E59B64BAA3579D5F0E
            name : Terminator.Genisys.2015.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi
            path : C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Hardcore.Henry.2015.SLOSubs.DVDRip.XviD-DrSi
        },
        {
            id : 084D1BDC1FDF82264A3554E59B64BAA3579D5F0E
            name : Terminator.Genisys.2015.SLOSubs.BRRip.XviD-DrSi
            path : C:\\Users\\davidvuckovic7\\Downloads\\Hardcore.Henry.2015.SLOSubs.DVDRip.XviD-DrSi
        }
    ]
}
```

You know, what I mean? Your torrents-array contains a lot of arrays. The data in the second array are always the same. For this you can use a object instead of an array! There is not need to use an array again!

To get data you can to something like this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
String build : obj.getJSONObject("build");
JSONArray torrents = obj.getJSONArray("torrents");
```

Now you can simply loop through the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < torrents .length(); i++) {
    JSONObject torrent = torrents.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = torrent.getString("name");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes the JSON is terrible. However it's just how it looks like when I get it from the API, so I can't change it.